# Docker compose, set local volume mapping with version 3

Tags: docker-compose

Probably simple, but I dont find any thing about this. My composer config file (version 3), define two volumes to be shared with others services :

```
version: "3"
  services:
    nginx:
      build: docker/nginx
      ports:
        - "80:80"
      volumes:
        - config:/etc/nginx/conf.d
        - data:/var/http
      networks:
        - default
      container_name: nginx

networks:
  default:

volumes:
  config:
  data:
```

How to set/attach the local directories (ex. d:/nginx/etc, d:/nginx/http) mapped to this volumes on the config file (or the docker-compose up command) ?

Comment: Note. Virtualbox docker-machine host, have a shared folder named /devel mapped to d:/nginx. I have try to test a setting like " - ./etc:/etc/nginx/conf." but no way, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try to replace your `volumes` lines this way :

`data:/var/http` -> `path/to/local/dir:/var/http`

Moreover assuming that you are running Windows, it should look like this :

```
- //d/nginx/etc:/etc/nginx/conf.d
- //d/nginx/http:/var/http
```

Then remove the global `volumes` section.